# find consecutive days with condition

Tags: r

I want to add a new column in my dataframe that count the consecutive days with a condition: Count the consecutive days if the "return" ist higher than 3.

Here is my dataset:

```
df <- tibble( 
date = lubridate::today() +0:9,
return= c(1,2.5,2,3,5,6.5,1,9,3,2))
```

My dataframe should look like this:

```
   date       return    Consec_days
   <date>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 2019-02-20    1         NA
 2 2019-02-21    2.5       NA
 3 2019-02-22    2         NA
 4 2019-02-23    3         NA
 5 2019-02-24    5         1
 6 2019-02-25    6.5       2
 7 2019-02-26    1         NA
 8 2019-02-27    9         NA
 9 2019-02-28    3         1
10 2019-03-01    2         NA
```

If the condition is not met, then give me "NA" or "0"

I already tried:

```
df$Consec_Days <- with(df, ave(return, data.table::rleid(return > 3), 
                               FUN = function(x) ifelse(return > 3, seq_along(x), 0L)))
```

But it does not work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(return_rleid = {return_rleid = rle(return > 3); rep(seq_along(return_rleid$lengths), return_rleid$lengths)}) %>%
 mutate(Consec_days = ifelse(return <= 3, NA, seq_along(return_rleid))) %>%
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-return_rleid)

   date       return Consec_days
   <date>      <dbl>       <int>
 1 2019-02-20   1.00          NA
 2 2019-02-21   2.50          NA
 3 2019-02-22   2.00          NA
 4 2019-02-23   3.00          NA
 5 2019-02-24   5.00           1
 6 2019-02-25   6.50           2
 7 2019-02-26   1.00          NA
 8 2019-02-27   9.00           1
 9 2019-02-28   3.00          NA
10 2019-03-01   2.00          NA
```

First, it performs a grouping by the run-length group ID. Second, if "return" is bigger than 3, it creates a sequence around the run-length group ID, otherwise assigns. Finally, it ungroups and removes the redundant variable.

Or the same but generating the sequence by `gl()`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(return_rleid = {return_rleid = rle(return > 3); rep(seq_along(return_rleid$lengths), return_rleid$lengths)}) %>%
 mutate(Consec_days = ifelse(return <= 3, NA, gl(length(return_rleid), 1))) %>%
 ungroup() %>% 
 select(-return_rleid)
```

Comment: but in the eighth row is a 1, though the 1 should be in the ninth row

Comment: Can you please explain why should it by in the ninth row if your criteria is "count the consecutive days if the "return" is higher than 3".?

Comment: Excuse me. That was my fault. But in the ninth row there should not be a 1.

Comment: @T.Kel I am confused now. What is your actual expected output? Should the ninth row have 1 or not? Also note that "greater than 3" is different from "greater than equal to 3".

Comment: @tmfmnk I have to apologize again. It works in this dataframe. But in another dataframe I still had problems. That's why I was a little confused

Answer (score 2):

An option using base R `ave` and `data.table::rleid`

```
library(data.table)
df$Consec_days <- with(df, (return > 3) * ave(return, rleid(return > 3), FUN = seq_along))


#     date       return Consec_days
#   <date>      <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 2019-02-20    1             0
# 2 2019-02-21    2.5           0
# 3 2019-02-22    2             0
# 4 2019-02-23    3             0
# 5 2019-02-24    5             1
# 6 2019-02-25    6.5           2
# 7 2019-02-26    1             0
# 8 2019-02-27    9             1
# 9 2019-02-28    3             0
#10 2019-03-01    2             0
```

Using `rleid(return > 3)` we create groups and then use `seq_along` and create sequence of observation for each group

```
with(df, ave(return, rleid(return > 3), FUN = seq_along))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 1 1 1 2
```

We multiply it with `(return > 3)` to keep observations which are greater than 3 and rest all are turned to 0.

---

Translating it into `dplyr` we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = rleid(return > 3)) %>%
  mutate(consec_days = (return > 3) * row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)
```

Comment: there is the same problem in your code: in the eighth row is a 1, though the 1 should be in the ninth row